# Store Array into NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsuserdefaults

I've got a small problem with permanently storing my Array using NSUserDefaults.

extract of my ViewController.m

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *locationArray;

- (IBAction)onAddClick:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"onAddClick");
    CLLocationDegrees lat = self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees longi = self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude;
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:longi];
    [self.locationArray addObject:currentLocation];

    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.locationArray];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"locationData"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

And in my LocationTableViewController.m I want to retrieve that array:

```
    NSData* data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"locationData"];
    self.locationArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

    if (data != nil) {
        NSLog(@"found data");
    }

    if (self.locationArray.count > 0) {
        NSLog(@"found array");
    }
```

When I dont close the app, everything works fine and I can retrieve the data from Userdefaults.. After closing, the data doesn't exist anymore... I thought NSUserDefaults is designed to store data permanently? Some tips?

Comment: Initialize locationArray before retrieving it from UserDefaults. or Print the [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]; to check whether array exists or not

Comment: Should you be using `NSUserDefaults` to pass data between view controllers?

Comment: I tried with array into NSUserDefault. I can insert and fetch easily.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is where you archived the array object which contains `CLLocation` object, `NSUserDefault` could save some types of objects like `NSData, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray`, and the object contained in NSArray should be also one of these types.

So `archivedDataWithRootObject` each `CLLocation` object to `NSArray`, means `NSArray` contains `NSData` in it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think array initialization should be done before use of that array like:

```
self.locationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score -2):

Initialize locationArray before retrieving it from UserDefaults.

```
NSData* data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"locationData"];

    self.locationArray =  [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    self.locationArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    if (data != nil) {
        NSLog(@"found data");
    }

    if (self.locationArray.count > 0) {
        NSLog(@"found array");
    }
```

Comment: That will not help.

Comment: And an array can have zero elements, so the check self.locationArray.count > 0 is wrong.